# Delaunay tessellation in Python?

Tags: python, graphics, delaunay

I need to find the Delaunay tessellation of a polygon in Python, and the only libraries I could find (Delny, scikits) triangulate point clouds, not polygons. Any suggestions?

Comment: A polygon does not necessarily _have_ a Delaunay triangulation. You need __constrained Delaunay__.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) has a Python binding. I'll try to get it working

Comment: I've used Triangle without any issues on python24

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), the Delaunay triangulation is defined for a set of points, not for a polygon. Could you just pass the set of the polygon's points into one of those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried matplotlib.delaunay.interpolate [link text](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) or Delny [link text](http://flub.stuffwillmade.org/delny/)?

Comment: matplotlib's docs say that the algorithm fails in certain cases, and Delny only accepts point clouds.